# 301 redirection doesn't happen in redirect module when we save path alias of a node in Source

Tags: 8, redirection

I installed [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) module in Drupal 8 and here during adding redirect it accepts and save the data for all valid value.

But when I try to save the path alias of a node in source, it saves successfully, but the redirection does not happen; the same happens when I save node/{id} in source redirection happen properly.

Why isn't the path alias redirected in case of saving it in to the source?

Wildcard is also not working.

Comment: `when I try to save the path alias of a node in source it saves successfully` are you adding this by editing the database or are you using redirect's form (/admin/config/search/redirect/add) ?

Comment: I have used form to save path-alias -- /admin/config/search/redirect/add

Comment: did you clear the cache?

Comment: Try to do the same on a fresh Drupal install in [here](https://simplytest.me/project/redirect)

Comment: Ok I'm trying installing this module again after clearing cache. As, if this gets done, will it support wildcard requests too? like http://test-d8.local/quarter-reports/% ?

Comment: `will it support wildcard requests too?` Unfortunately, no.